# a differential equation with matrices

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this system of equation:
$$
Mx''(t)+(K+N)x'(t)+(D+G)x(t)=F(t)
$$
$ x(0)=0 $ where M, K, N, D, G are matrix
I tried substitution $ z=(x, x') $

Comment: Well, that substitution is where I would start - then move to eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Please post your work.